# Cannot map from nullable integer to custom type that extends object

Tags: c#, wcf, automapper

I'm trying to map a nullable integer to some custom type (`RelatieBase`) that was generated from a WSDL. The type `RelatieBase` is defined as follows:

```
public partial class RelatieBase : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The code in my AutoMapper configuration looks like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FromType, ToType>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PropertyOfTypeRelatieBase, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SomeNullableInteger))
```

I have tried the following things:

- Assigning the integer directly to the `RelatieBase` property.
- Casting the integer to `RelatieBase` before assigning.
- Casting the integer to `object` before assigning.
- `opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SomeNullableInteger.Value)`

I would be thankful if someone is able to point out the mistake that I am making.

Comment: Do you want to use the `value` of the `nullable integer`? `Mapper.CreateMap<FromType, ToType>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PropertyOfTypeRelatieBase, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SomeNullableInteger.GetValueOrDefault()))` (@stuartd edited)

Comment: @Ian that will [throw an exception if the value has not been set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6(v=vs.110).aspx), better to use `src.SomeNullableInteger.GetValueOrDefault()`

Comment: I do not understand. Can you explain how do you expect to map an integer onto a specific object? Which result do you expect?

Comment: .. and what result do you get? An error? The value is not mapped?

Comment: @Ian Same error when using `.Value`.

@FedericoDipuma I need to map the value of the int? field to that `RelatieBase` field. The `RelatieBase` type was generated from a WSDL. There should be some way to assign a value to it I suppose.

@stuartd The error:
`Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Int32 -> RelatieBase
System.Int32 -> SomeWsdlNamespace.RelatieBase

Destination path: ToType.PropertyOfTypeRelatieBase

Source value: 8958`

Comment: RelatieBase is a class, you can't to map a base type to a class. It does not even make sense. Please tell us what you want to achieve so we may help you understand why this is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I overlooked some types that extend `RelatieBase` and can have some value.